PC crashes after I STOP playing a game or end a stress test
It runs fine while I'm playing, browsing or doing any task; even when I ran a stress test with AIDA64, but whenever I close the game and the PC cools down, it's shuts down or crashes. This started happening after I cleaned the PC. When I removed the cooler, the CPU came with it and bent a couple pins, but I fixed it and now I have this weird problem. Also, to get it to turn on with 2 ram sticks I had to fiddle around with the cooler screws, loosening them slightly until it powers on.
I performed a Windows memtest and it came out with no problems. I also disabled PBO with no results.
Specs:
R5 5600x with stock cooler
RTX 3070
2x8GB @3200MT/s
Motherboard ASRock B450 steel legend.
EVGA 650W PSU
Any help is appreciated, thanks!
Here is the analysis of the memory dump:
3: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION (3b)
An exception happened while executing a system service routine.
Arguments:
Arg1: 00000000c0000005, Exception code that caused the BugCheck
Arg2: fffff802636bf113, Address of the instruction which caused the BugCheck
Arg3: ffff8c809e3f2900, Address of the context record for the exception that caused the BugCheck
Arg4: 0000000000000000, zero.

Debugging Details:
------------------

*** WARNING: Check Image - Checksum mismatch - Dump: 0x7dd2, File: 0x159e7 - C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\hal.dll\1865382A6000\hal.dll
*** WARNING: Check Image - Checksum mismatch - Dump: 0x7dd2, File: 0x159e7 - C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\hal.dll\1865382A6000\hal.dll

KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
    Value: 3374

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 13268

    Key  : Analysis.IO.Other.Mb
    Value: 6

    Key  : Analysis.IO.Read.Mb
    Value: 0

    Key  : Analysis.IO.Write.Mb
    Value: 26

    Key  : Analysis.Init.CPU.mSec
    Value: 249

    Key  : Analysis.Init.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 52073

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 93

    Key  : Bugcheck.Code.KiBugCheckData
    Value: 0x3b

    Key  : Bugcheck.Code.LegacyAPI
    Value: 0x3b

    Key  : Bugcheck.Code.TargetModel
    Value: 0x3b

    Key  : Dump.Attributes.AsUlong
    Value: 800

    Key  : Failure.Bucket
    Value: MEMORY_CORRUPTION_LARGE

    Key  : Failure.Hash
    Value: {e29154ac-69a4-0eb8-172a-a860f73c0a3c}

    Key  : Hypervisor.Enlightenments.ValueHex
    Value: 1497cf94

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.AnyHypervisorPresent
    Value: 1

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.ApicEnlightened
    Value: 1

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.ApicVirtualizationAvailable
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.AsyncMemoryHint
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.CoreSchedulerRequested
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.CpuManager
    Value: 1

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.DeprecateAutoEoi
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.DynamicCpuDisabled
    Value: 1

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.Epf
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.ExtendedProcessorMasks
    Value: 1

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.HardwareMbecAvailable
    Value: 1

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.MaxBankNumber
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.MemoryZeroingControl
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.NoExtendedRangeFlush
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.NoNonArchCoreSharing
    Value: 1

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.Phase0InitDone
    Value: 1

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.PowerSchedulerQos
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.RootScheduler
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.SynicAvailable
    Value: 1

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.UseQpcBias
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.Value
    Value: 4853999

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.ValueHex
    Value: 4a10ef

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.VpAssistPage
    Value: 1

    Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.VsmAvailable
    Value: 1

    Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.AccessStats
    Value: 1

    Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.CrashdumpEnlightened
    Value: 1

    Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.CreateVirtualProcessor
    Value: 1

    Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.DisableHyperthreading
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.HostTimelineSync
    Value: 1

    Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.HypervisorDebuggingEnabled
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.IsHyperV
    Value: 1

    Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.LivedumpEnlightened
    Value: 1

    Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.MapDeviceInterrupt
    Value: 1

    Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.MceEnlightened
    Value: 1

    Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.Nested
    Value: 0

    Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.StartLogicalProcessor
    Value: 1

    Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.Value
    Value: 1015

    Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.ValueHex
    Value: 3f7

    Key  : SecureKernel.HalpHvciEnabled
    Value: 0

    Key  : WER.OS.Branch
    Value: ni_release

    Key  : WER.OS.Version
    Value: 10.0.22621.1


BUGCHECK_CODE:  3b

BUGCHECK_P1: c0000005

BUGCHECK_P2: fffff802636bf113

BUGCHECK_P3: ffff8c809e3f2900

BUGCHECK_P4: 0

FILE_IN_CAB:  MEMORY.DMP

DUMP_FILE_ATTRIBUTES: 0x800

FAULTING_THREAD:  ffffd70c19f0b080

CONTEXT:  ffff8c809e3f2900 -- (.cxr 0xffff8c809e3f2900)
rax=0000000000000000 rbx=ffff8c809e3d1180 rcx=ffffd70c19a42080
rdx=0000000000000100 rsi=ffffd70c19f0b080 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=fffff802636bf113 rsp=ffffd40d7c35f5e0 rbp=004fe07fb8bbbdff
 r8=01008e11006070f6  r9=00000000000000a0 r10=0000000000000082
r11=000000000000022b r12=0000000000000200 r13=ffffd70c19a42080
r14=ffffd70c0aafe040 r15=ffff8c809e3e0000
iopl=0         nv up di pl zr na po nc
cs=0010  ss=0018  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00050046
nt!KiUpdateSpeculationControl+0x1b3:
fffff802`636bf113 c9              leave
Resetting default scope

PROCESS_NAME:  logi_lamparray_service.exe

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffd40d`7c35f5e0 fffff802`6381fb37     : 004fe07f`b8bbbdff 00000000`00000000 00000000`00400000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiUpdateSpeculationControl+0x1b3
ffffd40d`7c35f670 fffff802`6381f906     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!SwapContext+0x1c7
ffffd40d`7c35f6b0 fffff802`6365ffa5     : ffff8c80`9e3d1180 00000000`00000000 ffffd70c`0ab1e040 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSwapContext+0x76
ffffd40d`7c35f7f0 fffff802`636613c7     : ffffd70c`19f0b080 00000000`00000000 00000000`000012a0 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSwapThread+0xaa5
ffffd40d`7c35f940 fffff802`63656af9     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 ffffd70c`000000ea 00000000`0faa3db7 : nt!KiCommitThreadWait+0x137
ffffd40d`7c35f9f0 fffff802`63ae0a50     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 000000b2`00000002 : nt!KeDelayExecutionThread+0xf9
ffffd40d`7c35fa70 fffff802`6382b608     : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 ffffffff`ffffd8f0 00000000`00000000 : nt!NtDelayExecution+0x60
ffffd40d`7c35faa0 00007ffd`011f07b4     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x28
000000b2`a4fff718 00000000`00000000     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x00007ffd`011f07b4


CHKIMG_EXTENSION: !chkimg -lo 50 -d !nt
*** WARNING: Check Image - Checksum mismatch - Dump: 0x7dd2, File: 0x159e7 - C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\hal.dll\1865382A6000\hal.dll
    fffff80263543648-fffff8026354364a  3 bytes - nt!_guard_check_icall_fptr
    [ f0 23 70:80 11 82 ]
    fffff80263543650-fffff80263543652  3 bytes - nt!_guard_dispatch_icall_fptr (+0x08)
    [ 00 1b 81:d0 11 82 ]
    fffff80263600f80 - nt!MiDeleteSessionPdes+48
    [ f6:fb ]
    fffff802636093e7-fffff802636093e8  2 bytes - nt!MiMarkPfnVerified+2b (+0x8467)
    [ 00 de:80 9c ]
    fffff802636094e0-fffff802636094e1  2 bytes - nt!MiUpdateImagePfnImportRelocations+48 (+0xf9)
    [ 00 de:80 9c ]
    fffff802636094ee - nt!MiUpdateImagePfnImportRelocations+56 (+0x0e)
    [ f6:fb ]
    fffff8026360950d - nt!MiUpdateImagePfnImportRelocations+75 (+0x1f)
    [ f6:fb ]
    fffff8026360aba4 - nt!MiSetReadOnlyOnSectionView+b4 (+0x1697)
    [ f6:fb ]
    fffff8026360ac4d-fffff8026360ac4e  2 bytes - nt!MiSetReadOnlyOnSectionView+15d (+0xa9)
    [ 00 de:80 9c ]
    fffff8026360ac78 - nt!MiSetReadOnlyOnSectionView+188 (+0x2b)
    [ f6:fb ]
    fffff8026360ad65 - nt!MiSetReadOnlyOnSectionView+275 (+0xed)
    [ f6:fb ]
    fffff8026360adf5-fffff8026360adf7  3 bytes - nt!MiSetReadOnlyOnSectionView+305 (+0x90)
    [ 40 fb f6:c0 fd fb ]
    fffff8026360de7f - nt!MmFreePoolMemory+127 (+0x308a)
    [ f6:fb ]
    fffff8026360e133-fffff8026360e134  2 bytes - nt!MiClearNonPagedPtes+1ab (+0x2b4)
    [ 00 de:80 9c ]
    fffff8026360e2b8-fffff8026360e2b9  2 bytes - nt!MiDeleteNonPagedPoolPte+98 (+0x185)
    [ 00 de:80 9c ]
    fffff8026360e50b - nt!MiDeleteNonPagedPoolPte+2eb (+0x253)
    [ f6:fb ]
    fffff8026360e61c - nt!MiRemoveFromSystemSpace+54 (+0x111)
    [ f6:fb ]
    fffff8026360e9f6 - nt!MiReturnSystemVa+56 (+0x3da)
    [ f6:fb ]
    fffff8026360ea11 - nt!MiReturnSystemVa+71 (+0x1b)
    [ f6:fb ]
    fffff8026360ecb7 - nt!MiInsertInSystemSpace+187 (+0x2a6)
    [ f6:fb ]
    fffff8026360f20e - nt!MiMakeZeroedPageTablesEx+de (+0x557)
    [ f6:fb ]
    fffff8026360f2a8-fffff8026360f2a9  2 bytes - nt!MiMakeZeroedPageTablesEx+178 (+0x9a)
    [ 00 de:80 9c ]
    fffff8026360f2c6-fffff8026360f2c7  2 bytes - nt!MiMakeZeroedPageTablesEx+196 (+0x1e)
    [ 00 de:80 9c ]
    fffff8026360fe70 - nt!MiInitializeColorBase+44 (+0xbaa)
    [ f6:fb ]
    fffff8026360fe7f - nt!MiInitializeColorBase+53 (+0x0f)
    [ f6:fb ]
    fffff80263610005-fffff80263610006  2 bytes - nt!MiDecommitLargePoolVa+7d (+0x186)
    [ 00 de:80 9c ]
    fffff80263610048-fffff8026361004c  5 bytes - nt!MiDecommitLargePoolVa+c0 (+0x43)
    [ d0 be 7d fb f6:70 ff fe fd fb ]
    fffff802636100f8-fffff802636100fc  5 bytes - nt!MiDecommitLargePoolVa+170 (+0xb0)
    [ df be 7d fb f6:7f ff fe fd fb ]
    fffff802636101c2 - nt!MiInsertLargeTbFlushEntry+2e (+0xca)
    [ f6:fb ]
    fffff802636102d9 - nt!MiExpandPtes+c9 (+0x117)
    [ f6:fb ]
    fffff80263610e7c - nt!MiCrcStillIntact+64 (+0xba3)
    [ f6:fb ]
    fffff80263610ec0-fffff80263610ec1  2 bytes - nt!MiCrcStillIntact+a8 (+0x44)
    [ 00 de:80 9c ]
    fffff80263611042-fffff80263611043  2 bytes - nt!MiMakeCombineCandidateClean+62 (+0x182)
    [ 00 de:80 9c ]
    fffff80263611087 - nt!MiMakeCombineCandidateClean+a7 (+0x45)
    [ f6:fb ]
    fffff802636111c1 - nt!MiSplitPrivatePage+75 (+0x13a)
    [ f6:fb ]
    fffff8026361125e - nt!MiSplitPrivatePage+112 (+0x9d)
    [ f6:fb ]
    fffff802636112db-fffff802636112dc  2 bytes - nt!MiSplitPrivatePage+18f (+0x7d)
    [ 00 de:80 9c ]
    fffff802636115a4 - nt!MiSplitPrivatePage+458 (+0x2c9)
    [ f6:fb ]
    fffff802636115ed - nt!MiSplitPrivatePage+4a1 (+0x49)
    [ f6:fb ]
    fffff80263611785 - nt!MiCopyToUserVa+55 (+0x198)
    [ f6:fb ]
    fffff802636117e4 - nt!MiCopyToUserVa+b4 (+0x5f)
    [ f6:fb ]
    fffff80263611843-fffff80263611844  2 bytes - nt!MiCopyToUserVa+113 (+0x5f)
    [ 00 de:80 9c ]
    fffff802636118ec-fffff802636118ed  2 bytes - nt!MiCopyToUserVa+1bc (+0xa9)
    [ 00 de:80 9c ]
    fffff80263611b13-fffff80263611b14  2 bytes - nt!MiChangePageAttributeBatch+17b (+0x227)
    [ 00 de:80 9c ]
    fffff80263611c0e-fffff80263611c0f  2 bytes - nt!MiTradeActivePage+4e (+0xfb)
    [ 00 de:80 9c ]
    fffff80263611c5e - nt!MiTradeActivePage+9e (+0x50)
    [ f6:fb ]
    fffff802636124c4 - nt!MiActivePageTradeable+78 (+0x866)
    [ f6:fb ]
    fffff80263612849-fffff8026361284a  2 bytes - nt!MiWriteComplete+169 (+0x385)
    [ 00 de:80 9c ]
    fffff80263612b81-fffff80263612b82  2 bytes - nt!MiWriteCompletePfn+71 (+0x338)
    [ 00 de:80 9c ]
    fffff8026361312f-fffff80263613130  2 bytes - nt!MiBuildMappedCluster+2f (+0x5ae)
    [ 00 de:80 9c ]
    fffff80263613219-fffff8026361321a  2 bytes - nt!MiBuildMappedCluster+119 (+0xea)
    [ 00 de:80 9c ]
    fffff802636132f0-fffff802636132f1  2 bytes - nt!MiBuildMappedCluster+1f0 (+0xd7)
    [ 00 de:80 9c ]
WARNING: !chkimg output was truncated to 50 lines. Invoke !chkimg without '-lo [num_lines]' to view  entire output.
    fffff80263a89ce6-fffff80263a89ce7  2 bytes - nt!PiDqQueryRelease+5a
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
    fffff80263a89ced-fffff80263a89cf1  5 bytes - nt!PiDqQueryRelease+61 (+0x07)
    [ 0f 1f 44 00 00:e8 ae ed 21 fc ]
    fffff80263a943a4-fffff80263a943a8  5 bytes - nt!NtTraceControl+364 (+0xa6b7)
    [ ff e0 cc cc cc:e8 f7 1c 46 00 ]
    fffff80263a9455e-fffff80263a94562  5 bytes - nt!NtTraceControl+51e (+0x1ba)
    [ ff e2 cc cc cc:e8 7d 1b 46 00 ]
    fffff80263a9efb2-fffff80263a9efb3  2 bytes - nt!MiValidateImagePfn+3a (+0xaa54)
    [ 00 de:80 9c ]
    fffff80263a9f007 - nt!MiValidateImagePfn+8f (+0x55)
    [ f6:fb ]
    fffff80263aa6a2e-fffff80263aa6a2f  2 bytes - nt!MiCreateNewSection+61a (+0x7a27)
    [ 00 de:80 9c ]
    fffff80263aa7ed4-fffff80263aa7ed8  5 bytes - nt!NtQueryInformationThread+2e4 (+0x14a6)
    [ ff e1 cc cc cc:e8 e7 e1 44 00 ]
    fffff80263aa872f-fffff80263aa8730  2 bytes - nt!MiProcessCrcList+bf (+0x85b)
    [ 00 de:80 9c ]
    fffff80263aa8744 - nt!MiProcessCrcList+d4 (+0x15)
    [ f6:fb ]
    fffff80263aa8751 - nt!MiProcessCrcList+e1 (+0x0d)
    [ f6:fb ]
    fffff80263aa8806 - nt!MiProcessCrcList+196 (+0xb5)
    [ f6:fb ]
    fffff80263aa8810 - nt!MiProcessCrcList+1a0 (+0x0a)
    [ f6:fb ]
    fffff80263aa8832-fffff80263aa8833  2 bytes - nt!MiProcessCrcList+1c2 (+0x22)
    [ 00 de:80 9c ]
    fffff80263aa8a34 - nt!MiProcessCrcList+3c4 (+0x202)
    [ f6:fb ]
    fffff80263aa8c8d - nt!MiProcessCrcList+61d (+0x259)
    [ f6:fb ]
    fffff80263aac49f-fffff80263aac4a3  5 bytes - nt!ExpQuerySystemInformation+1ff (+0x3812)
    [ ff e1 cc cc cc:e8 1c 9c 44 00 ]
    fffff80263aac4fb-fffff80263aac4ff  5 bytes - nt!ExpQuerySystemInformation+25b (+0x5c)
    [ ff e1 cc cc cc:e8 c0 9b 44 00 ]
    fffff80263aac56c-fffff80263aac570  5 bytes - nt!ExpQuerySystemInformation+2cc (+0x71)
    [ ff e1 cc cc cc:e8 4f 9b 44 00 ]
    fffff80263ab2382-fffff80263ab2386  5 bytes - nt!BuildQueryDirectoryIrp+c2 (+0x5e16)
    [ ff e1 cc cc cc:e8 39 3d 44 00 ]
    fffff80263abd0a7-fffff80263abd0a8  2 bytes - nt!CmCheckNoTxContext+f (+0xad25)
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
    fffff80263abd0ae-fffff80263abd0b2  5 bytes - nt!CmCheckNoTxContext+16 (+0x07)
    [ 0f 1f 44 00 00:e8 dd df f2 fb ]
    fffff80263ac2dde-fffff80263ac2de2  5 bytes - nt!VrpRegistryCallback+7e (+0x5d30)
    [ ff e1 cc cc cc:e8 dd 32 43 00 ]
    fffff80263ac2ef7-fffff80263ac2efb  5 bytes - nt!VrpRegistryCallback+197 (+0x119)
    [ ff e2 cc cc cc:e8 e4 31 43 00 ]
    fffff80263ad68dd-fffff80263ad68e1  5 bytes - nt!NtQueryInformationToken+15d (+0x139e6)
    [ ff e1 cc cc cc:e8 de f7 41 00 ]
    fffff80263ad8fda - nt!NtSetInformationThread+14a (+0x26fd)
    [ ff:e8 ]
    fffff80263ad8fdc-fffff80263ad8fde  3 bytes - nt!NtSetInformationThread+14c (+0x02)
    [ cc cc cc:d0 41 00 ]
    fffff80263ad9214-fffff80263ad9218  5 bytes - nt!NtSetInformationThread+384 (+0x238)
    [ ff e1 cc cc cc:e8 a7 ce 41 00 ]
    fffff80263add12d-fffff80263add131  5 bytes - nt!PspReferenceCidTableEntry+108d (+0x3f19)
    [ ff e1 cc cc cc:e8 8e 8f 41 00 ]
    fffff80263add969-fffff80263add96a  2 bytes - nt!PspReferenceCidTableEntry+18c9 (+0x83c)
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
    fffff80263add970-fffff80263add974  5 bytes - nt!PspReferenceCidTableEntry+18d0 (+0x07)
    [ 0f 1f 44 00 00:e8 7b fe c8 ff ]
    fffff80263ae0aa8-fffff80263ae0aa9  2 bytes - nt!MmQueryPfnList+48 (+0x3138)
    [ 00 de:80 9c ]
    fffff80263ae106d-fffff80263ae1071  5 bytes - nt!CmpCallCallBacksEx+54d (+0x5c5)
    [ ff e1 cc cc cc:e8 4e 50 41 00 ]
    fffff80263ae1274-fffff80263ae1278  5 bytes - nt!CmpCallbackFillObjectContext+54 (+0x207)
    [ ff e1 cc cc cc:e8 47 4e 41 00 ]
    fffff80263aebace-fffff80263aebacf  2 bytes - nt!MiRelocateImagePfn+ae (+0xa85a)
    [ 00 de:80 9c ]
    fffff80263aebade - nt!MiRelocateImagePfn+be (+0x10)
    [ f6:fb ]
    fffff80263aebb02 - nt!MiRelocateImagePfn+e2 (+0x24)
    [ f6:fb ]
    fffff80263aebb36 - nt!MiRelocateImagePfn+116 (+0x34)
    [ f6:fb ]
    fffff80263aec090-fffff80263aec094  5 bytes - nt!MiPfPrepareSequentialReadList+250 (+0x55a)
    [ d7 be 7d fb f6:77 ff fe fd fb ]
    fffff80263aec0a6-fffff80263aec0aa  5 bytes - nt!MiPfPrepareSequentialReadList+266 (+0x16)
    [ d0 be 7d fb f6:70 ff fe fd fb ]
    fffff80263aec35f-fffff80263aec363  5 bytes - nt!MiPfPrepareSequentialReadList+51f (+0x2b9)
    [ d7 be 7d fb f6:77 ff fe fd fb ]
    fffff80263aec444-fffff80263aec445  2 bytes - nt!MiPfPrepareSequentialReadList+604 (+0xe5)
    [ 00 de:80 9c ]
    fffff80263aee35f-fffff80263aee363  5 bytes - nt!NtSetInformationProcess+36f (+0x1f1b)
    [ ff e2 cc cc cc:e8 7c 7d 40 00 ]
    fffff80263aefbe5-fffff80263aefbe9  5 bytes - nt!NtSetInformationProcess+1bf5 (+0x1886)
    [ ff e2 cc cc cc:e8 f6 64 40 00 ]
    fffff80263b0c3e4-fffff80263b0c3e5  2 bytes - nt!PspGetProcessParameterOverrides+34 (+0x1c7ff)
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
    fffff80263b0c3eb-fffff80263b0c3ef  5 bytes - nt!PspGetProcessParameterOverrides+3b (+0x07)
    [ 0f 1f 44 00 00:e8 00 60 bf ff ]
    fffff80263b1c64d-fffff80263b1c64e  2 bytes - nt!ExpWnfGetNameStoreRegistryRoot+14d (+0x10262)
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
    fffff80263b1c654-fffff80263b1c658  5 bytes - nt!ExpWnfGetNameStoreRegistryRoot+154 (+0x07)
    [ 0f 1f 44 00 00:e8 97 11 c5 ff ]
    fffff80263b21904-fffff80263b21908  5 bytes - nt!NtQueryInformationProcess+314 (+0x52b0)
    [ ff e2 cc cc cc:e8 d7 47 3d 00 ]
    fffff80263b23c10-fffff80263b23c14  5 bytes - nt!NtQueryInformationProcess+2620 (+0x230c)
    [ ff e1 cc cc cc:e8 ab 24 3d 00 ]
WARNING: !chkimg output was truncated to 50 lines. Invoke !chkimg without '-lo [num_lines]' to view  entire output.
    fffff80263e87e97-fffff80263e87e98  2 bytes - nt!HalpMcaSetProcessorConfig+93
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
    fffff80263e87e9e-fffff80263e87ea2  5 bytes - nt!HalpMcaSetProcessorConfig+9a (+0x07)
    [ 0f 1f 44 00 00:e8 bd 99 bf fb ]
    fffff80263e880a3-fffff80263e880a4  2 bytes - nt!HalpInitializeMce+b3 (+0x205)
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
    fffff80263e880aa-fffff80263e880ae  5 bytes - nt!HalpInitializeMce+ba (+0x07)
    [ 0f 1f 44 00 00:e8 b1 97 bf fb ]
    fffff80263e880bc-fffff80263e880bd  2 bytes - nt!HalpInitializeMce+cc (+0x12)
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
    fffff80263e880c3-fffff80263e880c7  5 bytes - nt!HalpInitializeMce+d3 (+0x07)
    [ 0f 1f 44 00 00:e8 f8 a7 bf fb ]
    fffff80263e905bd-fffff80263e905be  2 bytes - nt!HalpInitializeMce+85cd (+0x84fa)
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
    fffff80263e905c4-fffff80263e905c8  5 bytes - nt!HalpInitializeMce+85d4 (+0x07)
    [ 0f 1f 44 00 00:e8 17 23 bf fb ]
    fffff80263e9063c-fffff80263e9063d  2 bytes - nt!HalpInitializeMce+864c (+0x78)
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
    fffff80263e90643-fffff80263e90647  5 bytes - nt!HalpInitializeMce+8653 (+0x07)
    [ 0f 1f 44 00 00:e8 c8 22 bf fb ]
    fffff80263e92208-fffff80263e92209  2 bytes - nt!HalpMcaResumeProcessorConfig+7c (+0x1bc5)
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
    fffff80263e9220f-fffff80263e92213  5 bytes - nt!HalpMcaResumeProcessorConfig+83 (+0x07)
    [ 0f 1f 44 00 00:e8 ec f2 be fb ]
    fffff80263e92da6-fffff80263e92da7  2 bytes - nt!HaliLocateHiberRanges+186 (+0xb97)
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
    fffff80263e92dad-fffff80263e92db1  5 bytes - nt!HaliLocateHiberRanges+18d (+0x07)
    [ 0f 1f 44 00 00:e8 be ea be fb ]
    fffff80263e9378f-fffff80263e93790  2 bytes - nt!HalpAcpiPostSleep+20f (+0x9e2)
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
    fffff80263e93796-fffff80263e9379a  5 bytes - nt!HalpAcpiPostSleep+216 (+0x07)
    [ 0f 1f 44 00 00:e8 c5 d8 b3 fb ]
    fffff80263e9b95c-fffff80263e9b95d  2 bytes - nt!KdMarkHiberPhase+34 (+0x81c6)
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
    fffff80263e9b963-fffff80263e9b967  5 bytes - nt!KdMarkHiberPhase+3b (+0x07)
    [ 0f 1f 44 00 00:e8 78 57 b3 fb ]
    fffff80263e9dacb-fffff80263e9dacc  2 bytes - nt!PopGracefulShutdown+15b (+0x2168)
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
    fffff80263e9dad2-fffff80263e9dad6  5 bytes - nt!PopGracefulShutdown+162 (+0x07)
    [ 0f 1f 44 00 00:e8 99 45 b4 fb ]
    fffff80263ea19b0-fffff80263ea19b1  2 bytes - nt!PopSaveHiberContext+1a0 (+0x3ede)
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
    fffff80263ea19b7-fffff80263ea19bb  5 bytes - nt!PopSaveHiberContext+1a7 (+0x07)
    [ 0f 1f 44 00 00:e8 94 f6 bd fb ]
    fffff80263ea9465-fffff80263ea9466  2 bytes - nt!MiMarkNonPagedHiberPhasePte+95 (+0x7aae)
    [ 00 de:80 9c ]
    fffff80263ea960c-fffff80263ea9610  5 bytes - nt!MiUpdateUserMappings+18 (+0x1a7)
    [ d0 be 7d fb f6:70 ff fe fd fb ]
    fffff80263ea96ac-fffff80263ea96b0  5 bytes - nt!MiUpdateUserMappings+b8 (+0xa0)
    [ d7 be 7d fb f6:77 ff fe fd fb ]
    fffff80263ea9bcd-fffff80263ea9bce  2 bytes - nt!MmMarkHiberPhase+5d (+0x521)
    [ 00 de:80 9c ]
    fffff80263eaa358 - nt!MiDeleteEnclavePages+60 (+0x78b)
    [ f6:fb ]
    fffff80263eaa566-fffff80263eaa567  2 bytes - nt!MiReturnReservedEnclavePages+26 (+0x20e)
    [ 00 de:80 9c ]
    fffff80263ead8b7-fffff80263ead8b8  2 bytes - nt!KdpSendWaitContinue+93
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
    fffff80263ead8be-fffff80263ead8c2  5 bytes - nt!KdpSendWaitContinue+9a (+0x07)
    [ 0f 1f 44 00 00:e8 0d 38 b2 fb ]
    fffff80263ead8f7-fffff80263ead8f8  2 bytes - nt!KdpSendWaitContinue+d3 (+0x39)
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
    fffff80263ead8fe-fffff80263ead902  5 bytes - nt!KdpSendWaitContinue+da (+0x07)
    [ 0f 1f 44 00 00:e8 bd 37 b2 fb ]
    fffff80263ead933-fffff80263ead937  5 bytes - nt!KdpSendWaitContinue+10f (+0x35)
    [ ff e1 cc cc cc:e8 88 87 04 00 ]
    fffff80263ead9c2-fffff80263ead9c3  2 bytes - nt!KdpSendWaitContinue+19e (+0x8f)
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
    fffff80263ead9c9-fffff80263ead9cd  5 bytes - nt!KdpSendWaitContinue+1a5 (+0x07)
    [ 0f 1f 44 00 00:e8 02 37 b2 fb ]
    fffff80263eadc04-fffff80263eadc05  2 bytes - nt!KdpReadVirtualMemory+9c (+0x23b)
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
    fffff80263eadc0b-fffff80263eadc0f  5 bytes - nt!KdpReadVirtualMemory+a3 (+0x07)
    [ 0f 1f 44 00 00:e8 c0 34 b2 fb ]
    fffff80263eadf90-fffff80263eadf91  2 bytes - nt!KdpCreateRemoteFile+12c (+0x385)
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
    fffff80263eadf97-fffff80263eadf9b  5 bytes - nt!KdpCreateRemoteFile+133 (+0x07)
    [ 0f 1f 44 00 00:e8 34 31 b2 fb ]
    fffff80263eadfda-fffff80263eadfdb  2 bytes - nt!KdpCreateRemoteFile+176 (+0x43)
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
    fffff80263eadfe1-fffff80263eadfe5  5 bytes - nt!KdpCreateRemoteFile+17d (+0x07)
    [ 0f 1f 44 00 00:e8 da 30 b2 fb ]
    fffff80263eae3ec-fffff80263eae3ed  2 bytes - nt!KdInitSystem+3ac (+0x40b)
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
    fffff80263eae3f3-fffff80263eae3f7  5 bytes - nt!KdInitSystem+3b3 (+0x07)
    [ 0f 1f 44 00 00:e8 68 2c b2 fb ]
    fffff80263eaeb05-fffff80263eaeb06  2 bytes - nt!KdSendTraceData+10d (+0x712)
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
    fffff80263eaeb0c-fffff80263eaeb10  5 bytes - nt!KdSendTraceData+114 (+0x07)
    [ 0f 1f 44 00 00:e8 bf 25 b2 fb ]
    fffff80263eaec25-fffff80263eaec26  2 bytes - nt!KdpReadControlSpace+95 (+0x119)
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
    fffff80263eaec2c-fffff80263eaec30  5 bytes - nt!KdpReadControlSpace+9c (+0x07)
    [ 0f 1f 44 00 00:e8 9f 24 b2 fb ]
    fffff80263eaeec4-fffff80263eaeec5  2 bytes - nt!KdpWriteControlSpace+6c (+0x298)
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
    fffff80263eaeecb-fffff80263eaeecf  5 bytes - nt!KdpWriteControlSpace+73 (+0x07)
    [ 0f 1f 44 00 00:e8 00 22 b2 fb ]
    fffff80263eaf5ac-fffff80263eaf5ad  2 bytes - nt!KdpPrintString+c0 (+0x6e1)
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
    fffff80263eaf5b3-fffff80263eaf5b7  5 bytes - nt!KdpPrintString+c7 (+0x07)
    [ 0f 1f 44 00 00:e8 18 1b b2 fb ]
    fffff80263eafde4-fffff80263eafde5  2 bytes - nt!KdpSendWaitContinue+25c0 (+0x831)
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
    fffff80263eafdeb-fffff80263eafdef  5 bytes - nt!KdpSendWaitContinue+25c7 (+0x07)
    [ 0f 1f 44 00 00:e8 e0 12 b2 fb ]
    fffff80263eb0b05-fffff80263eb0b06  2 bytes - nt!KdpCloseRemoteFile+ad (+0xd1a)
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
    fffff80263eb0b0c-fffff80263eb0b10  5 bytes - nt!KdpCloseRemoteFile+b4 (+0x07)
    [ 0f 1f 44 00 00:e8 af 05 b2 fb ]
    fffff80263eb0b58-fffff80263eb0b59  2 bytes - nt!KdpCloseRemoteFile+100 (+0x4c)
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
    fffff80263eb0b5f-fffff80263eb0b63  5 bytes - nt!KdpCloseRemoteFile+107 (+0x07)
    [ 0f 1f 44 00 00:e8 6c 05 b2 fb ]
    fffff80263eb0da7-fffff80263eb0da8  2 bytes - nt!KdpReadRemoteFile+e7 (+0x248)
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
    fffff80263eb0dae-fffff80263eb0db2  5 bytes - nt!KdpReadRemoteFile+ee (+0x07)
    [ 0f 1f 44 00 00:e8 1d 03 b2 fb ]
    fffff80263eb0de5-fffff80263eb0de6  2 bytes - nt!KdpReadRemoteFile+125 (+0x37)
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
    fffff80263eb0dec-fffff80263eb0df0  5 bytes - nt!KdpReadRemoteFile+12c (+0x07)
    [ 0f 1f 44 00 00:e8 cf 02 b2 fb ]
    fffff80263eb0ffa-fffff80263eb0ffb  2 bytes - nt!KdpFillMemory+fa (+0x20e)
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
    fffff80263eb1001-fffff80263eb1005  5 bytes - nt!KdpFillMemory+101 (+0x07)
    [ 0f 1f 44 00 00:e8 ca 00 b2 fb ]
    fffff80263eb10cc-fffff80263eb10cd  2 bytes - nt!KdpGetBusData+a4 (+0xcb)
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
    fffff80263eb10d3-fffff80263eb10d7  5 bytes - nt!KdpGetBusData+ab (+0x07)
    [ 0f 1f 44 00 00:e8 f8 ff b1 fb ]
    fffff80263eb116a-fffff80263eb116b  2 bytes - nt!KdpQueryMemory+7a (+0x97)
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
    fffff80263eb1171-fffff80263eb1175  5 bytes - nt!KdpQueryMemory+81 (+0x07)
    [ 0f 1f 44 00 00:e8 5a ff b1 fb ]
    fffff80263eb12ae-fffff80263eb12af  2 bytes - nt!KdpReadPhysicalMemory+126 (+0x13d)
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
    fffff80263eb12b5-fffff80263eb12b9  5 bytes - nt!KdpReadPhysicalMemory+12d (+0x07)
    [ 0f 1f 44 00 00:e8 16 fe b1 fb ]
    fffff80263eb160b-fffff80263eb160c  2 bytes - nt!KdpRestoreBreakPointEx+db (+0x356)
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
    fffff80263eb1612-fffff80263eb1616  5 bytes - nt!KdpRestoreBreakPointEx+e2 (+0x07)
    [ 0f 1f 44 00 00:e8 b9 fa b1 fb ]
    fffff80263eb181e-fffff80263eb181f  2 bytes - nt!KdpSearchMemory+1da (+0x20c)
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
    fffff80263eb1825-fffff80263eb1829  5 bytes - nt!KdpSearchMemory+1e1 (+0x07)
    [ 0f 1f 44 00 00:e8 a6 f8 b1 fb ]
    fffff80263eb1b8d-fffff80263eb1b8e  2 bytes - nt!KdpSetBusData+71 (+0x368)
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
    fffff80263eb1b94-fffff80263eb1b98  5 bytes - nt!KdpSetBusData+78 (+0x07)
    [ 0f 1f 44 00 00:e8 37 f5 b1 fb ]
    fffff80263eb1c55-fffff80263eb1c56  2 bytes - nt!KdpSetContext+ad (+0xc1)
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
    fffff80263eb1c5c-fffff80263eb1c60  5 bytes - nt!KdpSetContext+b4 (+0x07)
    [ 0f 1f 44 00 00:e8 6f f4 b1 fb ]
    fffff80263eb1ee2-fffff80263eb1ee3  2 bytes - nt!KdpWriteBreakPointEx+14e (+0x286)
    [ 48 ff:4c 8b ]
WARNING: !chkimg output was truncated to 50 lines. Invoke !chkimg without '-lo [num_lines]' to view  entire output.
9324 errors : !nt (fffff80263543648-fffff80263eb2e5f)

MODULE_NAME: memory_corruption

IMAGE_NAME:  memory_corruption

MEMORY_CORRUPTOR:  LARGE

STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr 0xffff8c809e3f2900 ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  MEMORY_CORRUPTION_LARGE

OS_VERSION:  10.0.22621.1

BUILDLAB_STR:  ni_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {e29154ac-69a4-0eb8-172a-a860f73c0a3c}

Followup:     memory_corruption
---------


Post the WinDBG analysis of the memory dump. However, if you bent CPU pins, that’s the most likely explanation and there really isn’t a fix for that situation especially if the pins cannot be straightened without breaking

The pins were straightened and there is no visible damage

Your system crashed due to an error within logi_lamparray_service.exe uninstalling it might be a good idea

you don't happen to have your fan lights set to show color based on system temperature, do you?

No, I didn't even configure the leds
